# How to define sample weights within custom loss function?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, loss-function

I require to classify binary sequences, where I want to have assign higher weight to later parts of the sequence.

For example, I want to assign:

```
sequence      -- weights for the samples in this sequence
[0,0,0,1,1,1] -- [1,1,1,2,3,4]
```

Input is in shape m x n, thus m samples of length n.

I want to assign weights within a custom loss function, as I want to learn how this works (and by using sample_weight I get all kinds of dimensionality problems).

Now I use the following loss function:

```
def weightedLoss(weight):
    def binaryPart(yTrue,yPred):
        return K.mean(loss.binary_crossentropy(yTrue,yPred)*weight)  
    return binaryPart
```

With weight being a m x n matrix containing the sample weights. The error message I get is: (m=20000,n=63)

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [20000,63]
>      [[{{node loss_39/dense_120_loss/mul}}]]

I do not understand what this error means. dense_120 is here my output layer, giving as output shape (None,63).

I feel like there is an error in the definition of my loss function, what am I missing?

Comment: Well... it's quite clear that you have data with shape 64 and a model outputting shape 63.

Comment: I used a batch_size of 64 (chosen at random), which seems to influence things. Putting it on 63 gives the same error, but now with [45] vs [20000,63]. Putting it on 1 lets me run my script. Can you please explain to me why batch_size matters?

Comment: You need to provide sufficient information about what you are doing. It's not possible to judge why your output shapes are behaving weird.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, your output layer should contain 64 neurons, but it looks like it currently contains 63. This should fix your error.

To answer your question regarding sample weights, the Keras .fit method already takes an argument for sample_weights, so you can use this without creating a custom loss function.

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1)
```

Comment: Sample_weights requires me to play with the dimensionalities of my data, which I am trying to avoid. I checked input/output etc. everything is the same size.

Comment: sample_weights only requires you to pass a 2D array if your data is time-series - but it sounded like it wasn't? Some more details would help people answer, like a model.summary() and the shape of your data